# Should I use vector logo in website?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, vector, logo

Should I use vector logo in SVG format in website? To make responsive logo in responsive website.
Need suggestions, which format will be best?

Comment: Most of web browser are supporting SVG format, and the responsiveness depends on the complexity of the logo (which will be rendered by the browser itself) and on the hardware of the device. The advantage of SVG is the resizeability and the interaction with Javascript. It all depends on the kind of site you are designing and on the expected clients. Can you tell us more about?

Comment: Related question is regarding different issue. Neither answer to the linked question is focusing on the question _whether or not_ SVG should be used for logos, but explaining how to achieve that from a more technical point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely.

Pros:

- **Scalability** - Without changing the image quality. A one stop shop for retina logos :)
- **Small size**. SVG image elements take up much less space than raster formats
- **Flexibility**. Simply use CSS to change to color, shape or position. Even animate.

Cons:

- Can't really think of any except maybe some types of logo might result in a larger file size than you'd like.

Comment: Probable con: SVG logos are scalable, thus it's easier to use them for fraudulent stuff, e.g. when providing 150px width PNG logo visitors can't grab the logo for use in a fake letter used to trick a brand's customers. I can't use that for starting fake merchandise or creating any large-scale prints. Infringements become much easier when offering scalable version of your brand for public download.